# Ruby string "nil" to nil:NilClass nil (reverse of nil.inspect)

Tags: ruby

I wonder howto get from a string "nil" the nil:NilClass?

`nil.inspect -> "nil"`

I wish something like:

`"nil".to_nil -> nil`

Update:

As I write in the comment bellow it's easier to :

`params[:form].each_pair{|k,v| fields[k] = k.to_s.include?('_id') ? v.to_nil : v`

then

`params[:form].each_pair{|k,v| fields[k] = k.to_s.include?('_id') ? (v == "nil" ? nil : v) : v }`

Comment: Why? Just why would you want to do this? This sounds like you are attempting to shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: In a db I have some fields with default values, but sometimes I need to create them with nil value. In a forms input I can't send the nil value because then the create statement assigns the default, so I needed a way to handle this. For now the best solution what I find was to send the "nil" as the inputs value and before creating the new record parse the params hash and replace all "nil" with nil:NullClass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-open the string class if you want this functionality globally.

```
class String
  def to_nil
    if self == 'nil'
      nil
    else
      self
    end
  end
end

'nil'.to_nil # => nil
'another string'.to_nil # => "another string"
```

Comment: Perhaps the question wasn't clear, but this is what I need :)

Answer (score 4):

I don't see the point of a `to_nil`, because well, it's always `nil`, so write `nil`. But if your question is which is the inverse operation of `inspect`, you can use `eval`:

```
eval("nil") #=> nil
```

Comment: Is String.eval a Rails thing?

Comment: @steenslag: probably, I checked in a Rails console. Turn to standard eval.

Answer (score 0):

You could eval the string "nil" for example:

```
=> eval("nil").nil?
irb> true
```